# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException when displaying matched lines

Tags: java

I have an issue in my android code. My objective of this code to read each lines of a text file to match with static string also i need to display all matched questions.
My static input string is "what is your DOB" and also having a text(fms.txt) file which has all questions in assets folder. Then i have compiled this code. i got the output with errors.

My code

```
try {
    ins = this.getAssets().open("fms.txt");
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
    line = reader.readLine();
    message = "What is your DOB";
    messages = message.split(" ");
    int i = 0, j = 0, inc = 1, oldin = 0;
    while (line != null) {
        lines = line.split("#");
        words = lines[0].split(" ");
        if (words[0].trim().equals(messages[0].trim())) {
            for(i = 1; messages[i].trim() != null; i++) {
                Log.e(TAG, "----------::::"+messages[i].trim());
                oldin = inc;
            }
        }
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    ins.close();
    Log.e(TAG, "---------FMSG : "+finalmsg);
} catch(IOException e1) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing here ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because you still have somewhere white space in your comparision

replace

```
for(i=1; messages[i] != null, i++)
```

with

```
for(i = 1; i < messages.length && messages[i] != null && !messages[i].trim().isEmpty(); i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in your `for(i=1; messages[i].trim() ...` because `i` sometime will be greater or equal than the length of your `messages` array. In order to solve, you should change the code to:

```
for (i = 1; i < messages.length && messages[i] != null &&
            !messages[i].trim().isEmpty(); i++) {
    //your business logic...
}
```

Explaining the changes:

- `i < messages.length`: this must be the first rule. Note that Java evaluates from left to right. When iterating on an array, you **must first** check if the index is less than the array size.
- `messages[i] != null`: secondly, check that the array element is different from `null`. If you do `messages[i].trim()` over a `null` instance, you will get a `NullPointerException`.
- `!messages[i].trim().isEmpty()`: at last, after you know you can access to the element and this element is not `null`, you can trim the leading spaces and check if the `String` is not empty.

Note that this error is not an android application error, instead a Java wrong coding.

Further revision, you don't need to worry about `messages[i]` being `null`, not even empty. Your code should just be

```
for (i = 1; i < messages.length; i++) {
    //your business logic...
}
```

---

By the way, next time please don't post an image of your code, instead write it on your question. If you don't understand how to format the code, don't worry, somebody else would edit the question and give you a hand. Same advice for stacktraces.